# Calculate seismic attributes for area near to given wells in PETREL

Tags: petrel, exploratory

I have **well log data** of 17 wells for a given area, and  **seismic data** for the same area. How do I calculate **seismic attributes** in areas near to each well(say, a 10-meter radius from the well) using **PETREL** software?

Till now, what I have tried is, importing the **wells** and **seismic data(3D)**. Then, cropping the volume near to each well, calculating a **seismic attribute** over that volume and then exporting as a **.segy** file. But, this is a very time consuming and tedious approach, and I am not even sure if it is right.

So, I'd like to know if there is an alternative, systematic approach?